# Change two sets of datatypes daily then reset them

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I need to change two sets of image data and two sets of text data daily for an iOS app. The first image set is x1-13.png , the second is y1-20.png. In all there are 260 combinations (13x20 days) before they repeat the cycle. There are 2x260 sets of text data (textA, textB) that run along side. They have to corespond to specific gregorian dates and cycle through their combinations. The app will open, look at what date it is and load the corresponding data. It also needs to **SKIP OVER A LEAP YEAR DAY (2/29)..**

[Within the image 260combinations, there are are additional image combinations (example below) but I have worked out the various formulas/coding for these - they rely on both sets starting at day one (x1.png,y1.png)and will work on implementation.]

At the moment all I can do manually change two sets of ints as counters to show different images. Eg:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;

-(void)getImage{

if (y) {
UIImage *theYimg = [UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SetY%i.png", y]];
    [MainImageView setImage:theYimg];

int additionalImagery;
if ((x == 2 ||x == 7||x==12) && y <9) {
        additionalImagery = y + 12;
        UIImage *addimg = [UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SetY%i.png", additionalImagery]];
        [secondImageView setImage:addimg];
        UIImage *thirdimg = [UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SetX%i.png", x]];
        [thirdImageView setImage:thirdimg];
}
```

Is there a loop that can count up (++) **daily** till they reach the end of the image set and then reset themselves from the first image again? - the equivalent of :

```
int x = 1; x <=13; x++; //then reset to x=1 again after 13days

int y = 1; y <=20; y++; //then reset to y=1 again after 20days
```

The cycles will begin on the same day but obviously they will need to reset on different days.

and **equally importantly**

How do I implement them in a daily schedule?

Comment: You need to provide way more context in your question. What kind of program are you writing? A simple desktop app? Or is it a driver? Or a daemon, server, or some other long-running process? How does it start? When does it stop?

Comment: I believe you're better of saving a date then comparing that date when the app loads. If its been 13+ days do what you need to do. But having you app count in the background once per day is both wasteful of resources and may not even work if the app is force closed or killed by the watchdog.

Comment: I was trying to be as direct as possible but i can elaborate to give a better idea - edit

Comment: better edit this morning

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a counter/reset method which seems to be working. However I have only used an NSTimer interval to check this:

```
-(void)countUpAndReset{

x++;
if (x <= 13) {
    [self getImage];
}
else if (x > 13){
    x = 1;
    [self getImage];
}

y++;
if (y <=20) {
    [self getImage];
}
else if (y >20){
    y = 1;
    [self getImage];
}
}
```

and in the ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

x = 1;
y = 1;

[self getImage];
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(countUpAndReset) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Now I have to map it onto a gregorian calendar starting on a date eg. 12/25/2010 to (++) every day (minus leap year day 2/29)..?